# C# sorting strings small and capital letters

Tags: c#, string, sorting, case-sensitive

Is there a standard functionality which will allow me to sort capital and small letters in the following way or I should implement a custom comparator:

```
student
students
Student
Students
```

For an instance:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Dela.Mono.Examples
{
   public class HelloWorld
   {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         List<string> list = new List<string>();
         list.Add("student");
         list.Add("students");
         list.Add("Student");
         list.Add("Students");
         list.Sort();

         for (int i=0; i < list.Count; i++)
             Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
      }
   } 
}
```

it sorts the string as:

```
student
Student
students
Students
```

If I try to use `list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal)`, the sorting goes like:

```
Student
Students
student
students
```

Comment: you would need something custom here.

Comment: What would you like the outcome to be?

Comment: @ryadavilli: I was hoping for some more lazy solution! :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you only care about the capitalization of the first letter? What if later letters are capitalized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something on these lines

```
List<string> sort = new List<string>() { "student", "Students", "students", 
                                         "Student" };
List<string> custsort=sort.OrderByDescending(st => st[0]).ThenBy(s => s.Length)
                                                         .ToList();
```

The first one orders it by the first character and then by the length.
It matches the output you suggested by then as per the pattern i mentioned above else you will do some custom comparer

Comment: Thanks! This is working, but you need to correct the OrderBy to OrderByDescending!

Answer (score 1):

*I believe you want to group those strings which starts with lower case and upper case, then sort them separately.*

You can do:

```
list = list.Where(r => char.IsLower(r[0])).OrderBy(r => r)
      .Concat(list.Where(r => char.IsUpper(r[0])).OrderBy(r => r)).ToList();
```

First select those string which starts with lower case, sort them, then concatenate it with those strings which start with upper case(sort them). 
So your code will be:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("student");
list.Add("students");
list.Add("Student");
list.Add("Students");
list = list.Where(r => char.IsLower(r[0])).OrderBy(r => r)
      .Concat(list.Where(r => char.IsUpper(r[0])).OrderBy(r => r)).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
```

and output:

```
student
students
Student
Students
```