# Sorting a List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Uppercase and Lowercase

Tags: c#, sorting

```
var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AC", "123"));
parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Ab", "123"));
parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Db", "123"));
parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CD", "123"));

var sortParameters = parameters.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

this is my source,

Result is

```
Ab
AC
CD
Db
```

but I need result

```
AC
Ab
CD
Db
```

sort by Uppercase and Lowercase.

How can I fix it.

Comment: This might help. Same Issue as yours.
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/13642177/3530469

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple solution.

```
SortedDictionary<string, string> parameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
        parameters.Add("AC", "123");
        parameters.Add("Ab", "123");
        parameters.Add("Db", "123");
        parameters.Add("CD", "123");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `IComparer<string>` to do the sort for you.

Try this:

```
public class StringByCharComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var xcs = x.ToCharArray();
        var ycs = y.ToCharArray();
        return Compare(xcs, ycs);
    }

    private int Compare(IEnumerable<char> xs, IEnumerable<char> ys)
    {
        if (!xs.Any() || !ys.Any())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            var x = xs.First();
            var y = ys.First();
            var r = x.CompareTo(y);
            if (r == 0)
            {
                r = Compare(xs.Skip(1), ys.Skip(1));
            }
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
var sortParameters =
    parameters
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key, new StringByCharComparer())
        .ToList();
```

The results I get are:

```
Key    Value
AC     123 
Ab     123 
CD     123 
Db     123
```

---

I just learnt something from Seminda's answer.

You could just do this:

```
var sortParameters =
    parameters
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
        .ToList();
```

Simple.